Relationship between tensor product in Lie algebra and in quantum mechanics
If we treat dynamic operators like $P$ in quantum mechanics as generators in Lie algebra,and the square of operators like $P^2$ as elements in the universal enveloping algebra.
Then in this wiki https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_enveloping_algebra we know that the $P^2$ indeed lives in the enveloping algebra as $P\otimes P$.
But seems this tensor product not the same as the tensor product of operators in quantum mechanics. Whether they have relationships? Or whether we treat the $P\otimes P$ as $P^2$ may leads some problems?
I know there exist a problem but not directly connect to quantum mechanics.
If we consider the Pauli matrix rep of $su(2)$, then we know $\sigma_i^2=I$ so it commutes with all Pauli matrices and then should be a Casimir operator but it doesn't.

Given a matrix representation of a Lie Algebra, a representation of the Universal Enveloping Algebra follows by representing $A\otimes B$ as the matrix multiplication $\rho(A)\rho(B)$ of the representations $\rho(A) $ and $\rho(B)$ of $A$ and $B$ respectively.
One can check that this satisfies the definition of the Lie bracket of the Universal Enveloping Algebra :
$$[\rho (A), \rho (B)\rho (C)]=\rho (B) [\rho (A), \rho (C)] + [\rho (A), \rho (B)]\rho (C)$$
which is just a property of the matrix commutator.
So you are right that the tensor product in the Lie Algebra is not related to the tensor product in the Quantum Mechanics Hilbert space. Instead, it is identified with operator composition in the Hilbert space.
About the second question, in general, we have :
$$[S_1, S_2^2]=S_2[S_1, S_2]+[S_1,S_2]S_2=S_2S_3+S_3S_2$$
For the spin-1/2 representation of the algebra, the above expression is zero because the spin-1/2 matrices anti-commute. So, this commutator being zero is a specific to the spin-1/2 representation, and not to the Lie Algebra itself.
In general, $S_i^2$ is not proportional to identity because the eigenvalues of $S_i$ range from $-s$ to $s$ for a spin-s representation.

I have a question, if we consider the Pauli matrix rep of $su(2)$ as I mentioned in the question, the operator $J_i^2$ should be multiplication of two Pauli matrix,which is proportional to identity. So we can imply $J_i^2$ are Casimir operators for all i, how I got it wrong?

@MakiseKurisu i have edited it

OH I see thanks, so whether the logic here is: the representation of the tensor product is the matrix multipilication, but the commutation still keeps the behavior in universal enveloping algebra. So seems this rep is not faithful.

@MakiseKurisu yes. it still satisfies the commutation relations of the universal enveloping algebra (i.e.$ [S_1, S_2^2]=S_2S_3+S_3S_2$), but it's not a faithful rep because $\rho(S_i \otimes S_i)= \frac14 I$ for all $i$

And I found some aurthors prove that $[S_i,S^2]=0$ for spin operators by proving $S^2$ is proportional to I, so seems this step is not much correct

@MakiseKurisu $S^2= \sum S_i ^2$ is indeed a Casimir operator of the algebra. The individual $S_i^2$ are not

Yes, I mean, but the step to prove its the casimir is incorrect

Yes, OP is right.

When evaluating an tensor element, say, $$x\otimes y~\in~U(L), \qquad x,y~\in~L,$$ of the universal enveloping algebra of a Lie algebra $L$ in a Lie algebra representation $\rho:L\to {\rm End}(V)$, then the tensor $\otimes$ is replaced by composition $\circ$:
$$\rho(x\otimes y)~:=~\rho(x)\circ\rho(y) .$$

If we pick a basis for the vector space $V$, and we represent the 2 linear maps $\rho(x),\rho(y)$ by 2 matrices, then the composition $\circ$ is replaced by matrix multiplication.



The tensor product is a mathematical construction that builds a new vector space from vector spaces. It has a lot of applications in mathematics, including for Hilbert spaces, here it naturally plays the role of the right construction to represent Hilbert spaces of compound systems.
Now, to Lie algebras. There are Lie algebras that are built from pre-existing associative algebras, by defining the Lie bracket as the commutator of operators. A question arises: what if the Lie algebra is abstract, and not (in an obvious way) built in this way? Those are algebras for which « taking squares » has no meaning at all.
Then comes the notion of the universal enveloping algebra. The universal property defining this universal enveloping algebra says that we can recover the whole representation theory of the Lie algebra from the representation theory of the associative algebra.
One important thing to note is that, in the point of view of category theorists, whenever an object is defined by a universal property, every interesting thing should be derived from the universal property itself, and not from the actual construction of said object. As an example, here is the usual way mathematicians create the ring of integers $\mathbb{Z}$: we build an addition and a multiplication on a quotient of $\mathbb{N}\times \mathbb{N}$. But everyone is then urged to forget the details of this proof: nothing relevant about integers should depend on the fact that we built them from equivalence classes of pairs of nonnegative integers! For example, the statement $-2\in (3,5)$, despite being true, should be considered meaningless. The only important thing is that $\mathbb{Z}$ should be the smallest ring containing the semi-ring (not sure about the terminology, but it doesn’t matter) $\mathbb{N}$ ».
So, from this point of view, nothing interesting should be concluded from the details of how the universal enveloping algebra is built: in particular, the fact that the construction involves tensor products should be irrelevant. Moreover, the fact that the tensor product is the right way to describe the Hilbert spaces of compound systems could also be phrased in terms of a universal property should imply that the mathematical construction of tensor products should not be considered as fundamental in physics, but rather a technical tool. So, my answer would be: no, there is no connection between the tensor products in the situations you quote, because they are both technical tools that, according to the category-theoretic philosophy, should be forgotten.
Finally, you should also note that when a Lie algebra is a Lie subalgebra of $M_n(\mathbb{K})$, there is a natural candidate for a universal enveloping algebra: just take the associative subalgebra generated by the Lie subalgebra (this means: to compute products, just compute them as products in $M_n(\mathbb{K})$). I am not sure this is the universal enveloping algebra (and in fact, I think that this answer gives an example where it is not). Therefore, the product of elements in the universal enveloping associative algebra should not be confused with the product in the ambient associative algebra.
